# Conditional expectation with Radon Nikodym derivative is in $L^1(\Omega, \mathbb F, \mathbb Q)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation, radon-nikodym

Let $\mathbb {P, Q}$ be equivalent probability measures on $(\Omega, \mathbb F)$,  $X \in L^1(\Omega, \mathbb F, \mathbb Q)$, ${d\mathbb Q}\over {d \mathbb P}$ be the Radon Nikodym derivative and $ \mathbb G \subset \mathbb F$ a subsigma-algebra.

I know that ${{d\mathbb Q}\over {d \mathbb P}} \in L^1(\Omega, \mathbb F, \mathbb P)$ by de Radon Nikodym theorem, hence $\mathbb E_{\mathbb P}[{{d\mathbb Q}\over {d \mathbb P}}| \mathbb G]\in L^1(\Omega, \mathbb F, \mathbb P)$ and is positive with probability $1$

I was able to prove that given the hypothesis, the product $X{{d\mathbb Q}\over {d \mathbb P}}\in L^1(\Omega, \mathbb F, \mathbb P)$ and hence 
 $\mathbb E_{\mathbb P}[X{{d\mathbb Q}\over {d \mathbb P}}| \mathbb G]\in L^1(\Omega, \mathbb F, \mathbb P)$

My question: given that $X \in L^1(\Omega, \mathbb F, \mathbb Q)$ how can I show that

$${1 \over \mathbb E_{\mathbb P}[{{d\mathbb Q}\over {d \mathbb P}}| \mathbb G]}\mathbb E_{\mathbb P}[X{{d\mathbb Q}\over {d \mathbb P}}| \mathbb G] \in L^1(\Omega, \mathbb F, \mathbb Q)$$

and

$$ \mathbb E_{\mathbb Q}[X| \mathbb G]={1 \over \mathbb E_{\mathbb P}[{{d\mathbb Q}\over {d \mathbb P}}| \mathbb G]}\mathbb E_{\mathbb P}[X{{d\mathbb Q}\over {d \mathbb P}}| \mathbb G]$$

My issue is regarding the first question since the last one is just working out with the properties of conditional expectation. I would really appreciate any hints or suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to show that 
$$\mathbb{E}_\mathbb{Q} \left|{1 \over \mathbb E_{\mathbb P}[{{d\mathbb Q}\over {d \mathbb P}}| \mathbb G]}\mathbb E_{\mathbb P}\left[X{{d\mathbb Q}\over {d \mathbb P}}| \mathbb G\right]\right| < \infty.$$

By the conditional triangle inequality, it is enough to show
$$\mathbb{E}_\mathbb{Q} \left[{1 \over \mathbb E_{\mathbb P}[{{d\mathbb Q}\over {d \mathbb P}}| \mathbb G]}\mathbb E_{\mathbb P}\left[|X|{{d\mathbb Q}\over {d \mathbb P}}| \mathbb G\right]\right] < \infty.$$
But by definition of $\frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}}$, the latter is the same as showing
$$\mathbb{E}_\mathbb{P} \underbrace{\left[{1 \over \mathbb E_{\mathbb P}[{{d\mathbb Q}\over {d \mathbb P}}| \mathbb G]}\mathbb E_{\mathbb P}\left[|X|{{d\mathbb Q}\over {d \mathbb P}}| \mathbb G\right] \frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}}\right]}_{\text{call this $Y$}} < \infty.$$

Now note that $E_{\mathbb{P}}[Y] = E_\mathbb{P}[E_{\mathbb{P}}[Y | \mathbb{G}]]$ and use some properties of conditional expectation.

Comment: But doesn´t $Y$ need to be $\mathbb Q$ integrable in order to change the  measure to $\mathbb P$?   I think that is a property of the radon nikodym derivative and not a definition

Comment: @user128422: $Y$ is nonnegative, and the identity $\mathbb{E}_\mathbb{Q}[Y] = \mathbb{E}_\mathbb{P}[Y \frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}}]$ is valid for every nonnegative random variable, integrable or not.  (If it is not $\mathbb{Q}$-integrable then both sides will equal $+\infty$.)  The relevant properties of conditional expectation are also valid for all nonnegative random variables, without integrability assumptions.

Comment: @NateEldredge I wonder if the non-negativity of $Y$ is a necessary qualification in your comment? In other words, if $Y$ is measurable (but not necessarily integrable or non-negative), can we be certain that $\mathbb{E}_\mathbb{Q}[Y]$ and $\mathbb{E}_\mathbb{P}[Y\frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}}]$ exist or not simultaneously, and that if they exist, they are necessarily equal (including the $\pm\infty = \pm\infty$ situation)?

Comment: @paperskilltrees: Yes, indeed it is true for all random variables $Y$, in the sense you suggest.  Simply apply the nonnegative version to $Y^+$ and $Y^-$.  The "non-existent" case corresponds to when all the expectations equal $+\infty$; in all other cases it is valid to write $E[Y] = E[Y^+] - E[Y^-]$.